# Property of 10x10 matrix with non negative eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $10\times 10$ matrix with complex entries such that all its eigenvalues are non-negative real numbers, and at least one eigenvalue is positive.  Which of the following statements is always false ?

A. There exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB - BA = B$.
B. There exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB - BA = A$.
C. There exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB + BA = A$.
D. There exists a matrix $B$ such that $AB + BA = B$.

I just need a hint to start thinking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

B is always false. The trace of $AB-BA$ is always zero, but the trace of $A$, which is the sum of its eigenvalues, is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Since I read the question wrong, I will try a different way to at least show which answer you should suspect to be false. Namely, I will show that options A, C, and D are sometimes possible.

For A, let $B$ be the zero matrix. This shows that A holds for any choice of matrix $A$.

For C, Let $B$ be the diagonal matrix with diagonal entries equal to $\frac{1}{2}$. This shows C is true for any matrix $A$.

For D, let $A$ be the matrix $B$ above. This choice of $A$ meets the hypothesis, and for this choice of $A$, D holds for any other matrix $B$, so D is at least sometimes true.

Comment: Please tell something more.
I'm really stuck and confused about it.

Comment: @Katherine If $B$ commutes with $A$, then $AB+BA=AB+AB=2AB$. What kind of matrices commute with all other matrices?

Comment: scalar matrices, but I still dont get the point.
How can I say that no such matrix B exists.
You may reveal the answer.

Comment: @Katherine Oh god, I thought it said always true.....sorry!

Comment: I got it, since trace(AB)=trace(BA) implies option B is false.
Thanks for help

Comment: @Katherine no problem. I have edited my answer to show a different way of going about it that would show you at the very least which option you should try to disprove.

Answer (score 1):

We could also observe that the identity matrix satisfies all the conditions for the matrix A. Substituting it in the options given, we can easily conclude that option B is not true $(IB-BI=0\neq I)$.